# What are the pi-MOs in anisole like?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory

The $\pi$-orbitals of benzene are well known and given in any standard undergraduate textbook. When considering anisole, phenol, etc, a lone pair in a p orbital of the O can delocalise into the $\pi$-system of the aromatic ring. How would this affect the $\pi$-orbitals of the cyclic system? Is it possible to account for the effect of this delocalisation by starting with the benzene $\pi$-orbitals and then interact those with the p-orbital, or does the change in point group disallow this - surely if we used this method, we would mix each benzene MO in turn with the p-orbital to yield 12 MOs, which is clearly not the case?

Comment: You don't get 6*2 = 12 MOs, you get 6+1 = 7 MOs.

Comment: I understand that this is what I should get, however I am unable to actually get this. What I have been doing is considering each pi MO in turn for the benzene molecule, then adding a p-orbital on a C next to a ring carbon and looking at its overlap with the MOs. My issue is, the p-orbital can overlap constructively or destructively with any one benzene MO, which would give a cap of the p-orbital perturbing only one benzene MO to give rise to 2 more - the 6+1 situation. However, based on symmetry the p-orbital should be able to interact with 4 different benzene pi MOs (6*2 situation)?

Comment: Symmetry isn't the problem here; there's no way you can put 7 things in (6 benzene MOs + 1 p-orbital on oxygen) and get 12 things out.

Comment: A first-order answer to answer is relatively easy to compute with some basic linear algebra. Trying to qualitatively sketch out the MOs and get the relatively energies correct may be highly prone to error.

Comment: @orthocresol, in that case are you suggesting that the p orbital can only interact with one benzene MO?

Comment: @Zhe, I have tried a preliminary calculation using basic group theory, which gave me 5 b1 and 2 a2 orbitals in c2v. However I found constructing the form of all these orbitals difficult.

Comment: @K.P. no, not at all. You can have $m$ orbitals from fragment A interacting with $n$ orbitals with fragment B and *you will only get $m+n$ MOs from that* – no more and no less, and it doesn't depend on whether they are related by symmetry or not.

Comment: @K.P. The calculation does not require group theory at all, you just need to diagonalize a matrix and find it's eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Specifically, I assume that it's just a carbon $p$ orbital interacting with the ring. You can perturb the system with an oxygen orbital: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eigenvectors(%5B%5Ba,b,0,0,0,0,0%5D,%5Bb,a,b,0,0,0,b%5D,+%5B0,b,a,b,0,0,0%5D,+%5B0,0,b,a,b,0,0%5D,%5B0,0,0,b,a,b,0%5D,%5B0,0,0,0,b,a,b%5D,%5B0,b,0,0,0,b,a%5D%5D)

Comment: @Zhe for anisole, I would suggest a smaller absolute $\beta$ value and a larger absolute $\alpha$ value in the Hückel method. Maybe $0.8\beta$ and $1.2\alpha$?

Comment: @TAR86 Probably. I picked those values just so that I could get a faster answer out. :)